# writing to a file with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So I want to use buttons on my HTML page to call a php program that will write to a text file. What I currently get is a success package from my Ajax function, but the file that it has supposed to have written does not exist.

my HTML

```
<button type = "button" onclick = "getRequest('changeState.php', changeState('1'), 0)"></button>
```

my Javascript functions:

```
function getRequest(url, success, error) {
var req = false;
try{
    // most browsers
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
catch (e){
    // IE
    try{
        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    catch(e) {
        // try an older version
        try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch(e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
    if (!req) return false;
    if (typeof success != 'function') success = function () {};
    if (typeof error!= 'function') error = function () {};
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(req.readyState == 4) {
            return req.status === 200 ? 
            success(req.responseText) : error(req.status);
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null);
    return req;
}

function changeState(input)
{    
    state = input;
    document.GetElementById("state_current").innerHTML = state;
}
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php
    $f = fopen("file.txt");
    fwrite($f, "Hello World");
    fclose($f);
?>
```

I'll be honest, I'm very new to php, but my syntax seems fine because I'm not dropping any error messages, and I know that the program runs successfully because I get the success function to run. Have I missed something glaringly obvious?

Comment: your URL is working? did you verify it? just try to `echo "hello world!";` in your changeState.php

Comment: yeah, as @messerbill says. Try pointing your browser directly at a PHP file that just has `<?php echo "Oi Oi Saveloy!"; ?>` in it

Comment: Where are you looking for the file?  There's no fully-qualified path, so it's going to be in whatever the current working directory for the PHP process is.

Comment: Any reason you're not using jQuery for the Ajax? It would make this much simpler.

Comment: all the files are in my /var/www/ folder (I'm working on Raspbian), is not not okay?

Comment: @Barrie Reader localhost/test.php yields a page that simply has hello world on it.

Comment: @irishMTS what browser are you testing on? `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` is IE only I believe... If you're on a Raspberry Pi, you'll need a more robust solution.

Comment: Its currently Chromium, will probably stick with that. That particular function was taken from another answer, I haven't really been able to take the time to learn Ajax properly

Comment: You do have a HTTP server with PHP on your raspbian right? Or are you trying with `file://`?

Comment: Oh yeah, its an Apache web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file.txt should be created, if calling your PHP-script directly. If not probably PHP is not allowed to create it. Unfortunately its not that easy to understand which user is used to run PHP, and this user must have the rights to write to the webroot-folder of the server. As far as I know this depends on how PHP is executed (module vs CGI).

I would give it a try to change the folders access rights to "777" (anyone is allowed to do anything).

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how to change options like that in Linux (I'm using Raspbian), where do I go to make those adjustments?

Comment: You connect to your Raspi over network using puTTy or Bitvise (on Windows) do get to the terminal. The rest ist standard linux stuff. chmod is used to change user rights on files and folders.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to have done it. file.txt is getting created each time now that I've changed the permissions. I'm surprised that Raspbian didn't give PHP permissions for that folder when it installed, but whatever, it works now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The `changeState` function doesn't get called on success because you are passing the value returned by the `changeState` function not the function reference, should be:

```
<button type = "button" onclick = "getRequest('changeState.php', changeState, 0)"></button>
```

You can also check on the Network Tab on the Developers Tools to see if you actually sent the request to the URL. If you didn't, then there's something wrong with your URL or your server.

Comment: I don't understand, why is it then that when I press the button, the function gets called? I don't have anything set for the failure

Comment: `changeState(1)` is a function call, so in your original html, the function is being called and a value is being returned (`undefined`) instead of passing the function reference with `changeState`.

Comment: While this is also valid, the main problem turned out to be that PHP didn't have permission to access the folder I was in. This was really useful to know too though, so thanks for the help!